# Magento 2: Custom Admin Controller / Action Returns 404

Tags: magento2

I don't really know where is the problem as it seems I have done as it is explained in the official documentation (except I did stripped it down a little);

> Company/Module/etc/admin/html/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="custom" frontName="custom">
            <module name="Company_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);

        $result->setContents('Hello world');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I visit `http://magento.local.com/admin/custom` I get 404 page in admin panel (security keys in URLs are turned off)

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace is wrong for start, it should be `namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;`

Comment: You're right! I didn't notice that!